# Normal distributions with bounded means and variance are tight

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $(a_n)_n$ and $(\sigma_n^2)_n$ be sequences of real numbers with $\sigma_n^2>0$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$ and let $$\mathcal P = \{\Bbb P^{X_n} : X_n \sim \mathcal N (a_n,\sigma_n^2)\}.$$
>   Then $\mathcal P$ is tight if and only if there is a $K>0$ such that $|a_n|\leq K$ and $\sigma_n^2\leq K$ for all $n\in \Bbb{N}$.

Tightness of $\mathcal P$ means by defintion that for any $\epsilon >0$ there is a $R>0$ such that $$\Bbb P^{X_n}([-R,R])\geq 1-\epsilon.$$

I already managed to prove that if $\mathcal P$ is tight, then the $|a_n|$ and $\sigma_n^2$ are bounded by some $K>0$.
I'm stuck at proving the converse.

To this end, we suppose that $|a_n|\leq K$ and $\sigma_n^2\leq K$ for some $K>0$ and aim to show that for each $\epsilon>0$ we can find an $R>0$ with  $$\Bbb P(|X_n|\leq R)\geq 1-\epsilon,$$ or equivalently, $$\Bbb P(|X_n|>R)< \epsilon.$$
On an intuitive level, this means that the probability mass doesn't escape to infinity which makes sense when the mean and variance are bounded. But I struggle to write down a formal proof. What choice of $R>0$ satisfies the above condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the fact that $X_n \stackrel{d}{=} \sigma_n X + a_n$, where $X$ is a standard Gaussian.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Markov's Inequality and get a bound that works.